# how to parse this xml with LINQ

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq

My XML has multiple elements but when I try to parse them using LINQ, I just get one element. Something is wrong with my select statement, but I'm having a devil of a time understanding what is wrong. The Result should be a dictionary populated with the `InvoiceUid` and `InvoiceNumber` for all the (2) `invoiceListItems`

Here is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <invoiceListResponse>
      <invoiceList>
        <invoiceListItem>
          <invoiceUid>39165890</invoiceUid>
          <invoiceDate>2013-12-26</invoiceDate>
          <invoiceNumber>W10001888</invoiceNumber>
          <contactUid>8363070</contactUid>
        </invoiceListItem>
        <invoiceListItem>
          <invoiceUid>39149309</invoiceUid>
          <invoiceDate>2013-12-24</invoiceDate>
          <invoiceNumber>W100</invoiceNumber>
          <contactUid>8363070</contactUid>
        </invoiceListItem>
      </invoiceList>
    </invoiceListResponse>
```

and the meat of my code:

```
         Dim list As XmlDocument = proxy.Find(queries)

        Dim InvoiceList = XDocument.Parse(list.InnerXml)
        ' get all <InvoiceListItem> elements from the xdocumetn
        Dim InvoiceListItems = From invoiceListItem In InvoiceList...<invoiceList>
                                 Select invoiceListItem

        'go through each InvoiceListItem in InvoiceListItems
        For Each InvoiceListItem In InvoiceListItems
            Console.WriteLine("Uid is {0} and Invoice Number is {1}", InvoiceListItem...<invoiceUid>.Value, InvoiceListItem...<invoiceNumber>.Value)
            returnInvoiceList.Add(InvoiceListItem...<invoiceNumber>.Value, CType(InvoiceListItem...<invoiceUid>.Value, Integer))
        Next
        Return returnInvoiceList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your select statement is selecting `invoiceList` elements (of which there is only one). This should do what you expected:

```
Dim InvoiceListItems = From invoiceListItem In InvoiceList...<invoiceListItem>
                       Select invoiceListItem
```

Answer (score 0):

ah finally got it working by adding .Elements here:

```
For Each InvoiceListItem In InvoiceListItems.Elements
```